# Converting current time to Seconds in Java

Tags: java, datetime, time

I have a value of 64800 which is 18:00 in seconds, so I am in need of converting current time to seconds format which I would need to compare if it is after the 64800 or before.

```
int minutes=64800;
long hours = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(Long.valueOf(minutes));
long remainMinutes = minutes - TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds(hours);
System.out.println(String.format("%02d:%02d", hours, remainMinutes));
```

If I use `System.currentTimeMillis` I am unable to convert it

Comment: `System.currentTimeMillis` will return the milliseconds since Jan 1st 1970 whereas you seem to want to check whether it's 16:00 (4pm) already. Is that local time? Did you look at classes like `LocalTime` which provides methods like `now()` and `toSecondOfDay()`?

Comment: @Thomas thanks Thomas, using toSecondOfDay i am able to compare it

Comment: @Thomas I would do it the other way around. `LocalTime.now(desiredTimeZoneId).isBefore(LocalTime.ofSecondOfDay(64800))`. Similarly `isAfter`. I find it more readable, clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarizing my comments as well as Ole V.V's:

`System.currentTimeMillis()` will return the milliseconds since Jan 1st 1970 00:00,000 GMT so you can't use it directly if all you want is the seconds since the start of today.

Also note that due to timezones the current time millis for a certain local time of day may be different so calculating it yourself isn't advisable.

Instead you might use `java.time.LocalTime` in one of the following ways:

```
long currentSecondsToday = LocalTime.now().toSecondOfDay();
if( currentSecondsToday < 64800) { ... }
```

Or maybe more readable (thanks to Ole):

```
LocalTime target = LocalTime.ofSecondOfDay(64800);
if( LocalTime.now().isBefore(target) ) { ... }
```

Also note that `LocalTime.now()` will use your system's default timezone. To be independent from system settings you could use `LocalTime.now(ZoneId.of("your desired timezone id"))`.

Additionally, you might want to use a more readable variant of defining the "target" time, e.g. `18:00`, e.g. `LocalTime.of(18,0)` or `LocalTime.parse("18:00", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) to get the desired result.

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.Duration;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Duration duration = Duration.ofSeconds(64800);
    String desiredValue = String.format("%02d:%02d", duration.toHoursPart(), duration.toMinutesPart());
    System.out.println(desiredValue);
  }
}
```

**Output**:

```
18:00
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)** and about the `Duration` through Q/As tagged with [duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/duration+java).

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to get the current day seconds from 00:00 in case you want to do it using `System.currentTimeMillis()` and maths:

```java
long epoch = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L; // Epoch in seconds
long todaySeconds = epoch % (24*3600); // Current day seconds from 00:00
```

With `todaySeconds` you can compare with `64800` or whatever other value, but IMPORTANT, the `todaySeconds` doesn't include timezone info,  It's UTC time, if you need to compare with local time, then add the timezone offset (in seconds) using [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html):

```java
long tzOffsetSecs = java.time.ZonedDateTime.now().getOffset().getTotalSeconds();
todaySeconds += tzOffsetSecs;
```

To get the hour and minute:

```java
long hour = todaySeconds / 3600;
long minute = todaySeconds % 3600 / 60;
```

Comment: Probably won’t work. It would work for the UTC time zone, but that’s hardly where the OP lives.

Comment: As I said, using the Duration is the best option, this answer is to show that we can get the hh:ss from `System.currentTimeMillis()` if the UTC is not the case, you can convert the `todaySeconds` to your TZ, but too much work, maybe.

Comment: I thought I already had. :-) Your answer gives an incorrect result for real time zones that real users live in. There doesn’t exist a correct way to convert `todaySeconds` to a different time zone.

Comment: But @ole-v-v, you are assuming something that is not clear in the question, the reference time could be in UTC (It's common in distributed systems). Anyway, adding the TZ It was simple, I've updated the answer (I should have done it the first time)

Comment: You are getting the *raw* offset, which for Madrid I believe is 1 hour. I haven’t tested, but I believe that you are still getting wrong results the 7 months of the year where Spain is using summer time (DST). For a date before 1940, when Spain used Western rather than Central European Time, you will get wrong results during standard time and by coincidence correct results during summer time. Upholding my downvote.

Comment: Also the `TimeZone` class is poorly designed and contains nasty surprises, and it also long outdated. It is recommended we don’t use it.

Comment: According to [official doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimeZone.html) TimeZone figures out daylight savings, but you are right, maybe the new Java time API should be used, I'll try with ZoneOffset

Comment: Answer updated with TZ using "new" Java time API